# How to get list of non existing values in DB2?

Tags: sql, select, db2

I have a big list of SSNs that I need to check if it doesn't exist in the table. How do I do that?

I tried this:

```
SELECT SSN FROM TABLE1 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT SSN FROM TABLE1 WHERE SSN IN ('111111111','222222222', '333333333', '777777777'))
```

But got no result set.

Here SSNs: 111111111, 222222222 and 333333333 exist in the table. SSN: 777777777 doesn't exist in the table.

Comment: What do you mean by a big list 10, 1k, over a million?

Comment: @John around 2k

Comment: I'm not sure what the sql query for this would be.  Of course you could select the records that are there and programmatically eliminate the ones that are not.  Good question!

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
with temp(ssn) as (                              
 values                                          
  ( '111111111'),                                
  ('222222222'),                                 
  ('333333333'),                                 
('777777777')                                    
)                                                
select * from temp a where ssn not in (            
SELECT SSN FROM TABLE1 where ssn = a.ssn          
)
```

OR

```
select * from ( 
values ( '111111111'), ('222222222'), ('333333333'), ('777777777') 
)temp(ssn) 
where ssn not in ( select ssn from table1 )
```

Comment: I am getting illegal symbol exception(-104) when I run your query. Trying to figure out which part is throwing it.

Comment: I created the table and ran the query. Works fine

Comment: with temp(ssn) as (                      
 values                                  
  ( '111111111'),                        
  ('222222222'),                         
  ('333333333'),                         
('777777777')                            
)                                        
select * from temp where ssn not in (    
select ssn   from table1                 
)

Comment: I am getting DSN_INLINE_OPT_HINT error, after googling it found page that says VALUES is not implemented yet  in DB2 zOS, not sure if its true, here i sthe link: http://www.idug.org/p/fo/et/thread=22181

Comment: Which DB2 version are you using?

Comment: Use this:-> select *                        
from ( values                   
  ( '111111111'),               
  ('222222222'),                
  ('333333333'),                
('777777777')                   
)temp(ssn)                      
 where ssn not in (             
select ssn   from table1        
)

Comment: I use version 10.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137487/discussion-between-userusher-and-foxy).